# String to Dictionary Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example I have line like this:

```
iamonlywhoknock BREAKINGBAD
```

what means

```
'iamonlywhoknock BREAKINGBAD\n'
```

Its str, but I need to create Dict, like this:

```
{"iamonlywhoknock":"BREAKINGBAD"}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x='iamonlywhoknock BREAKINGBAD\n'.split(" ")
mydict={x[0]:x[1]}
```

This should work for you. It is basic string splitting :)

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
>>> s='iamonlywhoknock BREAKINGBAD\n'
>>> k, v = s.split()
>>> {k: v}
{'iamonlywhoknock': 'BREAKINGBAD'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer in this post is similar to your question:

[Splitting a semicolon-separated string to a dictionary, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186857/splitting-a-semicolon-separated-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

But you would probably want it to look like this:

```
s= 'iamonlywhoknock BREAKINGBAD\notherwhoknock BREAKINGBAD2'
dict(item.split(" ") for item in s.split("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'iamonlywhoknock BREAKINGBAD\n'
b = a.split()
c = {b[0]:b[1]}

print c
```