# split comma-separated key-value pairs with commas

Tags: python, parsing

a bit like this question:
[How to split comma-separated key-value pairs with quoted commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575708/how-to-split-comma-separated-key-value-pairs-with-quoted-commas)

But my question is:

```
line='name=zhg,code=#123,"text=hello,boy"'
```

Note, "text=hello,boy", NOT:text="hello,boy"

I'd like to separate the line to dict.
The output I want is:

```
"name":"zhg","code":"#123","text":"hello,boy"
```

How to get it using regex or shlex?

Comment: what would be the expected output?

Comment: think you mean `line='name=zhg,code=#123,text="hello,boy"'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I don't think he does.  If he did, his link would answer his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `csv.reader` with a suitably "file-like" string.

```
>>> import csv
>>> import StringIO
>>> line='name=zhg,code=#123,"text=hello,boy"'
>>> string_file = StringIO.StringIO(line)
>>> for row in csv.reader(string_file):
...  print row
...
['name=zhg', 'code=#123', 'text=hello,boy']
```

Comment: Thank you! then I can use str.split('=') to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with the regex or it won't be the most efficient. The code to parse such string  is straightforward using a single pass parser:

```
line='name=zhg,code=#123,"text=hello,boy"'


def read_quote(string):
    out = ''
    for index, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == '"':
            index += 2  # skip quote and comma if any
            return index, out
        else:
            out += char


def read(string):
    print('input', string)
    out = ''
    for index, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == ',':
            index += 1  # skip comma
            return index, out
        else:
            out += char
    # end of string
    return index, out

def components(string):
    index = 0
    while index < len(line):
        if string[index] == '"':
            inc, out = read_quote(string[index+1:])
            index += inc
            yield out
        else:
            inc, out = read(string[index:])
            index += inc
            yield out

print(dict([e.split('=') for e in components(line)]))
```

It prints the following:

```
{'text': 'hello,boy', 'code': '#123', 'name': 'zhg'}
```

You can implement `read` and `read_quote` using a regex if you really want to.

Comment: The code doesn't do validation and doesn't do error checking.