# How do I convert "key=value, key=value, ..." to csv when some values contain the delimiter as part of the value?

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning

I have a data set of the format `key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3...` where each key-value pair is separated from the others by a `", "`.

However, some values are long strings that contain `", "` as part of the value.

How can I correctly go through this data and convert it to csv?

I've tried using a `csv.reader`, but it doesn't work.

```
 data = row.lstrip('(').rstrip(')\n')                               
 reader = csv.reader(StringIO(data))                                
 for row2 in reader:                                                
     my_dict = {}                                                   
     for d in row2:                                                 
         my_dict[d.split('=')[0].lstrip()] = d.split('=', 1)[1]
```

Comment: I think a few sample rows would be useful.

Comment: Can the value contain a `=`? If so, how can you tell if `key1=1, key2=2` sets `key1` to `1` and `key2` to `2`, or if it sets `key1` to `1, key2=2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split comma-separated key-value pairs with quoted commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575708/how-to-split-comma-separated-key-value-pairs-with-quoted-commas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import re, itertools as it
def get_vals(d):
   r = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in it.groupby(re.findall('\w+\=|[^\s,]+', d), key=lambda x:x[-1] == '=')]
   return {r[i][-1][0][:-1]:', '.join(r[i+1][-1]) for i in range(0, len(r), 2)}

tests = ['key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3', 'key1=va, lue1, key2=valu, e2, test, key3=value3']
print(list(map(get_vals, tests)))
```

Output:

```
[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}, 
{'key1': 'va, lue1', 'key2': 'valu, e2, test', 'key3': 'value3'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @Ajax1234's sample, `re.split()` and lookahead:

```
import re
str="key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3, key1=va, lue1, key2=valu, e2, test, key3=value3"
re.split(", (?=[^ ]+=)",str)
['key1=value1', 'key2=value2', 'key3=value3', 'key1=va, lue1', 'key2=valu, e2, test', 'key3=value3']
```