# Can I avoid such cumbersome list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

There is a list, which includes the following data,

```
a = ['key1=value1','key2=value2','key3=value3',...,'key100=value100']
```

I write the code below, which converts the list to one dict in one line,

```
b = dict((list(item.split('='))[0], list(item.split('='))[1]) for item in a
```

(My Python version is 2.6, which doesn't support dictionary comprehension.)

My question:
Is there a way to rewrite the code, which is more condense? e.g.,

```
b=dict(x,y) for item.split('=') in a       [WRONG]
```

I felt `list(item.split('='))[0]` and `list(item.split('='))[1]` is really cumbersome.

**[Update]** 
 @TigerhawkT3, the link [Alternative to dict comprehension prior to Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069668/alternative-to-dict-comprehension-prior-to-python-2-7) doesn't solve my problem, because my question is nothing with learning how to write dict comprehension prior to Python 2.7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069668/alternative-to-dict-comprehension-prior-to-python-2-7

Comment: Why not `dict([x.split('=') for x in a])`?

Comment: Similar with Henriks': `b = dict(item.split("=") for item in a)`. Runs in python 2.7 not sure if 2.6 needs the `[]. Inspired from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186857/splitting-a-semicolon-separated-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary can be [initialized](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) with an iterable, returning iterables with exactly two objects. This should do it:

```
d = dict([item.split('=', 1) for item in a])
```

Alternatively, you could use `map()`:

```
d = dict(map(lambda item: item.split("=", 1), a))
```