# Passing dictionary elements as arguments to a function

Tags: python, string, function, dictionary, arguments

Seen a few answers to similar questions, but not built in functions/multiple entry dictionaries. Suppose I have a dictionary containing basemap arguments for different map projections;

```
Domains = {'TPCentral':["projection='geos',lon_0=-160,lat_0=0,resolution='l'"],
'World':["projection='robin',lon_0=0"]}
```

I would like to call the basemap function (from maplotlib) such that

```
m = Basemap(Domains['TPCentral'])
```

so that this would function equivalently as;

```
m = Basemap(projection='geos',lon_0=-160,lat_0=0,resolution='l')
```

Problem is this passes it as one long string, not sure how to break it up into seperate arguments (tried using *). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186857/splitting-a-semicolon-separated-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python).

Comment: I'm not trying to construct a dictionary though.

Comment: What about this: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters)

Comment: You can use the dictionary constructed with the answer above and pass it into the function directly with `func(**theDict)` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334655/passing-a-dictionary-to-a-function-in-python-as-keyword-parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
["projection='geos',lon_0=-160,lat_0=0,resolution='l'"]
```

is a list containing a single string. Using unpacking on it would result in a list of characters - which would almost surely be a lot larger than the amount of your arguments and surely not the arguments you want to send. You better use a dictionary to keep this values:

```
'TPCentral': {
    'projection': 'geos',
    'lon_0': -160,
    'lat_0': 0,
    'resolution': 'l'}
```

and then unpack with a keyword arguments unpacking:

```
m = Basemap(**Domains['TPCentral'])
```

---

If you are forced by this format, you can do a little of string processing, like

```
pairs = [x.split('=') for x in Domains['TPCentral'][0].split(',')]
Domains['TPCentral'] = {k: eval(v) for k, v in pairs}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. I didn't realise dictionaries can contain sublists/dictionaries, i.e. dict = {'x':{'y':{'z':'a=1'}}}

Comment: Just did - had to wait a couple of mins.