# Convert a comma separated string of key values pairs to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to convert a comma separated string with key value pairs separated by colon into a dictionary where value is expected to be a float. I'm able to do this to get a dict:

```
>>> s = 'us:0.9,can:1.2,mex:0.45'
>>> dict(x.split(':') for x in s.split(','))
```

which results in:

```
{'us': '0.9', 'can': '1.2', 'mex': '0.45'}
```

but not sure how to force the value to be not a string ie, I'm expecting this:

```
{'us': 0.9, 'can': 1.2, 'mex': 0.45}
```

How to force the values to be floats?

Thanks!

Comment: This is how you convert it to float: `float('0.9')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a semicolon-separated string to a dictionary, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186857/splitting-a-semicolon-separated-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about:

```
{k: float(v) for k, v in [i.split(':') for i in s.split(',')]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can be confusing but you can try this :

```
s = 'us:0.9,can:1.2,mex:0.45'

dict((a, float(b)) for a,b in [x.split(':') for x in s.split(',')])
```

The output :

```
{'us': 0.9, 'can': 1.2, 'mex': 0.45}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function for this:

```
s = 'us:0.9,can:1.2,mex:0.45'

def key_val_split(L):
    key, val = L.split(':')
    return key, float(val)

res = dict(key_val_split(x) for x in s.split(','))

{'us': 0.9, 'can': 1.2, 'mex': 0.45}
```

Comment: Works, but is probably overkill - this can be done inline with a comprehension.

Comment: One line isn't necessarily better (but probably is more efficient here). In my opinion, though, the verbose function is more readable.

Comment: Debatable.  In a short code snippet like this, sure.  If your `key_val_split` function is defined somewhere far away from where it's used and I have to go find it while I'm debugging an issue, then definitely not.  The comprehension is all in one place, and always displayed together.

Comment: There are *plenty* of examples where "displayed together" is an awful idea. But we can agree to disagree. Certainly I find this more readable. But I'm more of a functional guy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = 'us:0.9,can:1.2,mex:0.45'
t = {k:float(v) for k, v in dict(x.split(':') for x in s.split(',')).items()}
print(t)
```

Output is:

```
{'us': 0.9, 'can': 1.2, 'mex': 0.45}
```

Comment: While this does work, it's overworked.  It's creating a dictionary to iterate over to parse the floats - there's really no need for that if you just consume the inner list comprehension.  This is twice as many iterations as is necessary.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit confused. Isn't your answer creating a list of lists, and iterating over to parse the floats. Where this is creating a dictionary, where I iterate over to parse the floats? I'm confused on how this has twice as many iterations as necessary. Could you explain for my understanding? (although I agree with your solution)

Comment: Sure.  The crux of it is that you create a list of lists with `x.split(':') for x in s.split(',')` (more specifically, a generator, but that distinction isn't hugely relevant to this discussion), and then iterate over it in the call to `dict()` (the implementation of `dict(listOfTuples)` has to consume the list via iteration), then iterate over the dictionary via `.items()`.  There are two full iterations of the data.  Mine only iterates that inner-most list once time.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with 3rd party Pandas, you can do quite a bit with [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd

s = 'us:0.9,can:1.2,mex:0.45'

d = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(s), sep=':', header=None, lineterminator=',')\
      .set_index(0)[1].to_dict()

{'us': 0.9, 'can': 1.2, 'mex': 0.45}
```